# Modal jQuery doesn't work (bootstrap 4)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with jQuery. When I click on the link the modal opens and I want to pass the value of `data-href` to the button inside the modal.

Nothing happens when I click the button. Could you please help me?

Link

```
<a href="#" data-href="stackoverflow.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal">Link</a>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">         
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" href="">Go</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
    <script>
        $('#openModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>
```

jQuery/Popper/JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Make sure nothing else has the same ID. The above code works fine. here it is on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/81L3payk/

Comment: check it https://jsfiddle.net/81L3payk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the jQuery file on the head instead of the bottom of the body and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `shown` instead of `show`

`$('#openModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

Try This If you found this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" than replace "$" to "jQuery".

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#openModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var data_href = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-href');
    console.log('data_href: ' + data_href);

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', data_href);
    $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
});
```

What you did was good, but there was a little mistake in your code:

```
$(e.relatedTarget).data('href')
```

You were trying to get the attribute **href** but the attribute on the button you are looking for is **data-href**